# Error with reboot when trying to start Ubuntu gui

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to get the Ubuntu gui working on my computer (I currently have Windows 10). When I first open Ubuntu I get their command line. I've run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, both of which were successful, and then through taskel installed Ubuntu Desktop. I then entered sudo reboot and got the following message:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

When I try `sudo reboot -f` I get

```
Rebooting.
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
```

Again, I'm just trying to open the gui, so if simply rebooting won't do that then an alternative suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Really start again. Really. Ubuntu come with a GUI interface as standard. Or install Linux Mint. Ubuntu with an XP lookalike face.

Somehow you have got two bits of incompatible software there: so scrub it and start again.